# org.hibernate.annotations.Entity deprecated in Hibernate 4?

Tags: java, hibernate, deprecated

I am attempting to update to Hibernate 4 and I am getting that org.hibernate.annotations.Entity is deprecated. None of the documentation however seems to indicate that this is the case. Anyone have any insight into this?

```
@org.hibernate.annotations.Entity(dynamicUpdate = true)
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Yes it is deprecated in 4.0+:

```
Deprecate org.hibernate.annotations.Entity
Its individual attributes/values should become annotations. 
Schedule for removal in 4.1
```

You should use [`@DynamicUpdate`](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-6398) instead

Here is a [fixed JIRA](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-6395) talking about it.

Comment: Thanks. On this note, upgrading to Hibernate 4 is proving a bit tricky. I cannot even create a session factory:

Comment: Note that the `@DynamicInsert` annotation exists too.

Answer (score 9):

From [Hibernate Getting Started Guide](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/quickstart/en-US/html_single/#hibernate-gsg-tutorial-annotations-entity) :

> The `@javax.persistence.Entity` annotation is used to mark a class as
>   an entity. It functions the same as the class mapping element
>   discussed in Section 2.3, "The mapping file". Additionally the
>   `@javax.persistence.Table` annotation explicitly specifies the table
>   name. Without this specification, the default table name would be
>   EVENT).

Since org.hibernate.annotations.Entity has been deprecated you should use the Java EE annotation. Also, as tolitius already mentioned, for the annotation configurations of `@org.hibernate.annotations.Entity`, you should use the respective annotation, e.g. `@DynamicUpdate`.

Hope that helps.

---

Note: `Event` is the name of the class that is annotated in the example, this is why it states "default table name would be EVENT".

Answer (score 6):

Use the JPA @Entity annotation instead of the Hibernate @Entity annotation. Look in your imports, it should say

```
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
```

and not

```
    import org.hibernate.annotations.Entity;
```

Answer (score 2):

For future purpose, please refer the deprecated API list for **Hibernate 4.0**. The link is as follows:-
[Deprecated API](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/javadocs/deprecated-list.html)