# Spring - Hibernate Integration

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, hibernate

I am trying to integrate Spring 4 with Hibernate 4 and i am using eclipse ide with out maven dependencies,But i am getting below mentioned error:

Caused by: [java.lang.classnotfoundexception](http://java.lang.classnotfoundexception:') : org.hibernate.annotations.Entity

if any one has implemented already and working fine, So please can you share the project for reference so that i can understand the flow of integration, As i am new to spring and hibernate.I need some good guidance.

Comment: The error means that you are missing a JAR file on the classpath. You need to find the JAR file that contains the class `org.hibernate.annotations.Entity` and add it to your project in Eclipse. This file should be in `hibernate-core-4.x.x.Final.jar`

Comment: But note also that `org.hibernate.annotations.Entity` is deprecated, you should use the JPA annotation `javax.persistence.Entity` instead.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7985970/org-hibernate-annotations-entity-deprecated-in-hibernate-4

Answer (score -2):

you need to use some dependency, which you can find below :

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
   <version>3.2.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.5-Final</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
  <version>5.2.9.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

and if you are not using maven project then you need to download the `hibernate-entitymanager` and `hibernate-annotations` jar and add into build path and rebuild the project

Comment: Abishek says in his question above that he is not using Maven.

Comment: then download the jar of the  `hibernate-entitymanager` and `hibernate-annotations` and add the jar file into build path .

Comment: This will not answer the question OP say version 4 but why are you suggesting 5?

Comment: Also, you should not be mixing Hibernate 3.2, 3.5 and 5.2 jar files.

Comment: because version 4 is old and why you are using older version when new version is available.

Comment: Which versions of these jars will work? because i am using hibernate-annotations-4.0.5-Final.jar and hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar, and still i am getting same error.

Comment: If you can suggest me some link to go through step wise step, and i can learn integration with the latest version would be appriciate.

Comment: you can refer below link for tutorial and you can refer `pom.xml` from this site, where pom fole contain Hibernate 4 and Spring 4

 http://websystique.com/spring/spring4-hibernate4-mysql-maven-integration-example-using-annotations/

Comment: Thanks, above tutorial helped.